# Сделать падение объекта

Tags: javascript, css, svg, svg-animation, сss3

Хотелось бы увидеть, как возможно реализовать на `css` падение какого-то маленького объекта по касательной, ну или допустим падающую звезду или еще что-то такое. Очень интересно)

Comment: движение вдоль кривой?

Comment: Не важно,хочется понять сам смысл, как это сделать

Comment: зависит от желаемого результата, по прямой - проще

Comment: Если можете,продемонстрируйте пожалуйста

Comment: @Ankor добавлен новый ответ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вариантов множества.. Но раз в метках `CSS`, то вот два

**@keyframes и div**

Здесь анимируется именно позиция `div` (элемента);

```css
body {margin: 0; overflow: hidden;}
.block {
  display: block;
  width: 25vh;
  height: 25vh;
  background: url('https://www.mountainfamily.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Review-star.png') no-repeat center center / contain;
  animation: star 5s linear infinite;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
}

@keyframes star {
  to {
    left: 100%;
    top: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

**@keyframes и background-position**

А тут уже анимируется именно позиция background'а

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.snowContainer {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('http://zastavok.net/main/zima/1507481531.jpg') no-repeat center center / cover;
}

#snow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://yraaa.ru/_pu/27/15825154.png"), url("https://yraaa.ru/_pu/27/89961317.png"), url("https://yraaa.ru/_pu/27/21791255.png");
  animation: snow 20s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes snow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0, 0 0, 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 500px 1000px, 400px 400px, 300px 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="snowContainer">
  <div id="snow"></div>
</div>
```

P.s. за анимацию спасибо сайту Yraaa.

Answer (score 5):

Пример на JS, но меняю я атрибуты CSS, просто так легко задать псевдослучайное поведение.

Добавьте к стилю атрибут `transition` и установите желаемый параметр, который необходимо изменить, а дальше браузер сделает все сам.

```js
let r = i => Math.random()*(i||1);
setInterval(function() {

  let star = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.append(star)
  let s = star.style;
  
  s.width = `${11+r(11)}px`
  s.height = `${11+r(7)}px`
  s.backgroundColor = `hsl(${r(360)},${25+r(50)}%,${25+r(50)}%)`
  s.position = `absolute`
  s.transition = `${1+r(3)}s cubic-bezier(${r()},${r()},${r()},${r()}) ` 
  s.left = `${120+r(window.innerWidth-240)}px`
  s.top = `-30px`
  
  setTimeout(a => {
    s.top = `${130+r(30)}px`;
    s.transform = `rotate(${r(2000)-1000}deg)`
    s.backgroundColor = `hsl(${r(360)},${25+r(50)}%,${25+r(50)}%)`
    s.transform = `translate(${r(200)-100}px) rotate(${r(1000)-500}deg)`
  }, 100)
  
  setTimeout(a => s.backgroundColor = `hsl(${r(360)},${25+r(50)}%,${25+r(50)}%)`, r(500) + 100)
  setTimeout(a => s.opacity = 0, 6000);
  setTimeout(a => star.remove(), 9000);
  
}, 200)
```

Answer (score 5):

### Решение SVG

Имитация ударов бильярдных шаров о бортики по касательной.

В качестве бортиков выступают границы SVG полотна, которые можно ограничивать шириной и высотой в процентах, например: `width="50%" height="50%"`.

Анимация одного шарика:

```
<circle cx="50%" cy="20%" r="3%" fill="url(#grad_blue)" >

 <animate attributeName="cx" dur="3" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 <animate attributeName="cy" dur="2.8" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
</circle>
```

Радиус шарика равен `r="3%"`, следовательно, чтобы он не вылетел за правый бортик, максимальное смещение вправо по оси `Х-ов` не должно превышать 97%, аналогично смещение влево не более `3%`. То есть, шарик должен коснутся стенки и отлететь. 
Это реализуется в атрибуте `values="3%;97%;3%"`

Точно также реализуется анимация `attributeName="cy"` по оси `Y-ов`.

Взаимодействие двух анимаций для координат центра шарика `cx` и `cy` создаёт иллюзию удара по касательной и отскока.

**вариант с размерами: SVG`: width="50%" height="50%"`**

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="50%" height="50%" style="border:1px solid  grey;">

 <radialGradient id="grad_blue" cx="20%" cy="20%" r="100%" fx="30%" fy="30%">
   <stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="blue" offset="25%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,192)" offset="50%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,127)" offset="70%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,64)" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,0)" offset="100%"/>
 </radialGradient>   
 
  <!-- Синий шар -->
<circle cx="50%" cy="20%" r="3%" fill="url(#grad_blue)" >
  
 <animate attributeName="cx" dur="3" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 <animate attributeName="cy" dur="2.8" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
</circle>

 <radialGradient id="grad_red" cx="20%" cy="20%" r="100%" fx="30%" fy="30%">
   <stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="red" offset="25%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(192,0,0)" offset="50%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(127,0,0)" offset="70%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(64,0,0)" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,0)" offset="100%"/>
 </radialGradient>

   <!-- Красный шар -->
<circle cx="30%" cy="70%" r="3%" fill="url(#grad_red)" >

 <animate attributeName="cx" dur="2.7" values="97%;3%;97%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 <animate attributeName="cy" dur="3.1" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
</circle>
 
</svg>
```

**Вариант** -  `width="100%" height="25%"`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="25%" style="border:1px solid  grey;">

 <radialGradient id="grad_blue" cx="20%" cy="20%" r="100%" fx="30%" fy="30%">
   <stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="blue" offset="25%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,192)" offset="50%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,127)" offset="70%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,64)" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,0)" offset="100%"/>
 </radialGradient>   
 
  <!-- Синий шар -->
<circle cx="50%" cy="20%" r="3%" fill="url(#grad_blue)" >
  
 <animate attributeName="cx" dur="3" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 <animate attributeName="cy" dur="2.8" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
</circle>

 <radialGradient id="grad_red" cx="20%" cy="20%" r="100%" fx="30%" fy="30%">
   <stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="red" offset="25%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(192,0,0)" offset="50%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(127,0,0)" offset="70%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(64,0,0)" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,0)" offset="100%"/>
 </radialGradient>

   <!-- Красный шар -->
<circle cx="30%" cy="70%" r="3%" fill="url(#grad_red)" >

 <animate attributeName="cx" dur="2.7" values="97%;3%;97%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 <animate attributeName="cy" dur="3.1" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
</circle>
 
</svg>
```

**Вариант** - `width="25%" height="100%"`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="25%" height="100%" style="border:1px solid  grey;">

 <radialGradient id="grad_blue" cx="20%" cy="20%" r="100%" fx="30%" fy="30%">
   <stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="blue" offset="25%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,192)" offset="50%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,127)" offset="70%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,64)" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,0)" offset="100%"/>
 </radialGradient>   
 
  <!-- Синий шар -->
<circle cx="50%" cy="20%" r="3%" fill="url(#grad_blue)" >
  
 <animate attributeName="cx" dur="3" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 <animate attributeName="cy" dur="2.8" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
</circle>

 <radialGradient id="grad_red" cx="20%" cy="20%" r="100%" fx="30%" fy="30%">
   <stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="red" offset="25%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(192,0,0)" offset="50%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(127,0,0)" offset="70%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(64,0,0)" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,0)" offset="100%"/>
 </radialGradient>

   <!-- Красный шар -->
<circle cx="30%" cy="70%" r="3%" fill="url(#grad_red)" >

 <animate attributeName="cx" dur="2.7" values="97%;3%;97%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 <animate attributeName="cy" dur="3.1" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
</circle>
 
</svg>
```